# Pagination Controller Call API On every Index Before Reaching End of the Page or on initializing the page

Tags: flutter

```
`Scaffold( 
    body: Column(children: [
        Search(),
        PagedListView<int, dynamic>(
            pagingController: controller.pagingCtrl,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.h),
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
            builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<dynamic>(
                itemBuilder: (context, item, index) =>
                    _buildNewsCard(title: item?.title),
                firstPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (_) => _buildNewsCardSkeleton(6),
                newPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (_) => _buildNewsCardSkeleton(6)
                )
            )
      ],
    )
)`
```

Expecting to call API Only Once it reach the end of the page on scrolling

Answer (score -1):

```
///
/// Add PageRequestListener to _pagingController
/// and its callback will be called every time the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.
/// The callback will receive the page key that should be loaded next.
/// The callback should fetch the next page of items and append them to the _pagingController.
///
 _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) async {
     ///
     /// Fetch Items from API
     ///
     try {

    ///
    /// How much items will be fetched from API
    ///  
    final int _pageSize = 20;

     List<Object> newItems = List<Object>.empty(growable: true);

      try {
        ///
        /// Fetch Items from API
        ///
        await Service().getProductList(pageKey,  limit: _pageSize).then((value) {
          newItems.addAll(value);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        _pagingController.error = e;
      }

      final isLastPage = newItems.length < _pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
    });
```

Comment: Ive tried this, all this code i am including already , but the problem is solved by giving a height to the widget